# iOS10 didDiscoverPeripheral misses

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I have two iPhones side by side running same version of my app. One iPhone is updated to iOS 10, the other is iOS 9.2.  I have a Bluetooth LE device transmitting non-connectable broadcast advertisements.  The iOS 10 iPhone fails to detect ~30% of the adverts (failure to invoke didDiscoverPeripheral).

For several versions of iOS, have had no problem.  Has iOS 10 Core Bluetooth broken something?

Thx, Dave

Comment: I experienced the same problem, in iOS 10 the didDiscoverPeripheral take much time to find devices compare to iOS 9. I want to know more about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by powering cycling the phone, or resetting network connections.